# iOS app waiting list for customers

Tags: ios, app-store

I am building out a iOS & Android app. My app may not fully scale to support users and have some limited functionality out the gates. I wanted to put an invite list on the front of registration like [Mailbox](https://www.fastcodesign.com/1671952/the-ux-thinking-behind-mailboxs-800000-person-waiting-list) did a few years ago.

I was trying to read the Apple app store guidelines to creating a "waiting list / invite list" and couldn't get a clear picture. I assume Android is more flexible on this, so I figured I could start with Apple's guidelines first.

Here is what I can find.

In [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#after-you-submit), it says under 3.2.2 "UnAcceptable"

(v) Arbitrarily restricting who may use the app, such as by location or carrier.

In this specific case, I am not blocking by location or carrier. I am just putting up a wall to use the app since some of my users can use it in a limited form, but I can't open it up to everyone on Day 1.

I understand I can run a ["testflight"](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) release, but I wanted to make our app available in the App Store for anyone to download since it will be publicly available, just not fully ready for a million people to hit it. My understanding is that the testflight release requires a bit more work based on their docs and isn't as simple as just putting it in the public app store so anyone can get to it.

Comment: Heres a thought. Is registration required to use the app? For those people you register let them know you will email them when their registration becomes active. For those that already have a login (your initial users) they can use the app when it comes out of the gate. It would circumvent the policy for a short time. Be aware though that if someone downloads your app and cant use it right away you might start getting hit with bad reviews.

Comment: Also unless you are releasing flappy birds again you probably wont be releasing with "a million" people hitting it.

Comment: @logixologist, thanks for the info. Registration would be required to use the app. That is what I figured on your recommendation. I wasnt sure though what Apples rules were though around having people register and then putting them on a wait list officially. As their Rules don't explain it very well. Hence why I wanted to get some more specifics if there was an area that said "you can do this" but "you cant do that." Just didn't want to design and build it and then they block it.

Comment: ultimately apple decides what will be allowed and what will not be so really its a question for the apple developer support. We can tell you anything but its ultimately up to them.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has the ultimate authority for approving and rejecting apps in their app store so nothing on SO can really be perfect advice. If you are really concerned about approval, you can try to contact apple developers support. Here are a few things I would advise:

- Make sure in the developer notes for Apple when you submit to them you include a free account.
- In the notes for the app store let the users know that it may take up to __ hours for their registration to get activated.

My understanding is you are doing this to handle the volume of users as you are launching the app. Be advised though that if you start restricting users too much you will possibly get poor reviews. Only restrict usage if absolutely required. If you run into issues make sure you are communicating with the users so they understand.

Good luck with you new app!